# MySQL Inner Join with where clause sorting and limit, subquery?

Tags: mysql, join, limit

Everything in the following query results in one line for each invBlueprintTypes row with the correct information. But I'm trying to add something to it. See below the codeblock.

```
Select
  blueprintType.typeID,
  blueprintType.typeName Blueprint,
  productType.typeID,
  productType.typeName Item,
  productType.portionSize,
  blueprintType.basePrice * 0.9 As bpoPrice,
  productGroup.groupName ItemGroup,
  productCategory.categoryName ItemCategory,
  blueprints.productionTime,
  blueprints.techLevel,
  blueprints.researchProductivityTime,
  blueprints.researchMaterialTime,
  blueprints.researchCopyTime,
  blueprints.researchTechTime,
  blueprints.productivityModifier,
  blueprints.materialModifier,
  blueprints.wasteFactor,
  blueprints.maxProductionLimit,
  blueprints.blueprintTypeID
From
  invBlueprintTypes As blueprints
  Inner Join invTypes As blueprintType On blueprints.blueprintTypeID = blueprintType.typeID
  Inner Join invTypes As productType On blueprints.productTypeID = productType.typeID
  Inner Join invGroups As productGroup On productType.groupID = productGroup.groupID
  Inner Join invCategories As productCategory On productGroup.categoryID = productCategory.categoryID
Where
  blueprints.techLevel = 1 And
  blueprintType.published = 1 And
  productType.marketGroupID Is Not Null And
  blueprintType.basePrice > 0
```

So what I need to get in here is the following table with the columns below it so I can use the values timestamp and sort the entire result by profitHour

```
tablename: invBlueprintTypesPrices
columns:   blueprintTypeID, timestamp, profitHour
```

I need this information with the following select in mind. Using a select to show my intention of the JOIN/in-query select or whatever that can do this.

```
SELECT * FROM invBlueprintTypesPrices 
WHERE blueprintTypeID = blueprintType.typeID 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

And I need the main row from table invBlueprintTypes to still show even if there is no result from the invBlueprintTypesPrices. The LIMIT 1 is because I want the newest row possible, but deleting the older data is not a option since history is needed.

If I've understood correctly I think I need a subquery select, but how to do that? I've tired adding the exact query that is above with a AS blueprintPrices after the query's closing ), but did not work with a error with the

```
WHERE blueprintTypeID = blueprintType.typeID
```

part being the focus of the error. I have no idea why. Anyone who can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to check for NULL values in invBlueprintTypesPrices.  To mimic the `LIMIT 1` per TypeId, you can use the `MAX()` or to truly make sure you only return a single record, use a row number -- this depends on whether you can have multiple max time stamps for each type id.  Assuming not, then this should be close:

```
Select
  ...
From
  invBlueprintTypes As blueprints
  Inner Join invTypes As blueprintType On blueprints.blueprintTypeID = blueprintType.typeID
  Inner Join invTypes As productType On blueprints.productTypeID = productType.typeID
  Inner Join invGroups As productGroup On productType.groupID = productGroup.groupID
  Inner Join invCategories As productCategory On productGroup.categoryID = productCategory.categoryID
  Left Join (
    SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) MaxTime, TypeId
    FROM invBlueprintTypesPrices 
    GROUP BY TypeId
  ) blueprintTypePrice On blueprints.blueprintTypeID = blueprintTypePrice.typeID 
  Left Join invBlueprintTypesPrices blueprintTypePrices On 
    blueprintTypePrice.TypeId = blueprintTypePrices.TypeId AND
    blueprintTypePrice.MaxTime = blueprintTypePrices.TimeStamp 
Where
  blueprints.techLevel = 1 And
  blueprintType.published = 1 And
  productType.marketGroupID Is Not Null And
  blueprintType.basePrice > 0
Order By
  blueprintTypePrices.profitHour
```

Assuming you might have the same max time stamp with 2 different records, replace the 2 left joins above with something similar to this getting the row number:

```
Left Join (
    SELECT @rn:=IF(@prevTypeId=TypeId,@rn+1,1) rn, 
         TimeStamp, 
         TypeId, 
         profitHour, 
         @prevTypeId:=TypeId
    FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM invBlueprintTypesPrices 
          ORDER BY TypeId, TimeStamp DESC) t
       JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
  ) blueprintTypePrices On blueprints.blueprintTypeID = blueprintTypePrices.typeID AND blueprintTypePrices.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where you are putting the subquery.  If in the `select` clause, then you have a problem because you are returning more than one value.

You can't put this into the `from` clause directly, because you have a correlated subquery (not allowed).

Instead, you can put it in like this:

```
from . . .
     (select *
      from invBLueprintTypesPrices ibptp
      where ibtp.timestamp = (select ibptp2.timestamp
                              from invBLueprintTypesPrices ibptp2
                              where ibptp.blueprintTypeId = ibptp2.blueprintTypeId
                              order by timestamp desc
                              limit 1
                             )
     ) ibptp
     on ibptp.blueprintTypeId = blueprintType.TypeID
```

This identifies the most recent records for all the `blueprintTypeid`s in the subquery.  It then joins in the one that matches.

Comment: I didn't mention where I was putting the subquery because I tried several places and neither worked and I have idea where it's supposed to be. But I guess I do now. Couldn't get your reply to work exactly as I wanted, but it was close. Solved it through sgeddes' answer.

Thanks anyways